# How to boot with 1024X576 or 800x600, receiving black screen after install

Tags: boot, display-resolution

Hello I was able to install by adding boot options video=1024X576-24@60 as I know that to be my screens resolution and I was previously getting a black screen.

Now that I went through the install the computer is not able to boot and shows black screen again after booting.

Please help, 14 LTS, hp mini 1030nr

thanks!

Comment: I tried installing lubuntu and I'm getting the same BLACK SCREEN. Please help me get an OS installed I'm really loosing it here.

Comment: so peoples;

The only way I can boot is recovery mode+video=800x600-24@60 acpi=off nomodereset



What the heck is going on !!!!! ah!

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'` terminal command.

Comment: The original question was completely different. That's why I flagged it as a duplicate.